# Как получить HTML страничку в коде используя PYTHON

Tags: python, сокет, requests

Задача:

Передать URL к сайту. Получить HTML страничку в коде PYTHON.

ВАЖНО. Реализовать нужно, используя socket. Я смог реализовать используя библиотеку requests. Нужно переписать на сокеты.

Пример коды на requests

```
import requests

reg_get = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.blog/")
text = reg_get.text
print(text)
```

Были попытки реализации используя GOOGLE.
Однако они не принесли нужный результат.
Пример набросок:

```
import socket
request = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: https://stackoverflow.blog/\n\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("https://stackoverflow.blog/", 80))
s.send(request)
result = s.recv(10000)
while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(10000)
```

Как мне реализовать данную задачу ? Очень надеюсь, на вашу помощь.

Comment: Так как сайты www.cnn.com и stackoverflow.blog используют HTTPS, то обязательно нужно использовать модуль ssl

Comment: Та, я пробовал и с другими сайтами, где его нет. Оно возвращает не html структуру

Comment: А что возвращает?